# How to find values in an array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use vue and firestore.

I want to make a Like button.
So I want to make an array of likeuids so that each person can press the like button on the user's uid.

To do so, I have to find the value in the array with where, but I don't know how.

Or is there any other good way to implement the Like button other than to put useruid in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `array-contains` clause in a query:

```js
citiesRef.where("regions", "array-contains", "west_coast");
```

More about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Or store each like in a collection where the `uid` of the user who liked is the `id` of the doc. That way you just need to check if that reference exists.

Comment: Thank you I will try the latter one.